# Raspberry 4, USB serial connection error -71

Tags: raspberry-pi4, usbserial

I have a sensor with (Infrared LED) with a serial connection connected to Raspberry Pi 4B. The serial sensor has built in USB converter. The USB part of dmesg is:

```
[   10.815246] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   10.815292] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   10.836293] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[   10.836803] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   10.841453] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-model-b.bin failed with error -2
[   10.858600] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[   10.993336] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[   10.993383] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[   10.993447] cp210x 1-1.3.3:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[   10.998418] usb 1-1.3.3: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

The connection is running several days, but then the connection is interrupted. On dmesg the following error is shown:

```
[171331.973479] usb 1-1.3: clear tt 1 (9031) error -71
```

Recovery is can only be done by rebooting the raspberry. Stopping and starting the program does not help.

OS is OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

Thanks for any answer,
Johannes

Comment: My hunch would be, that the firmware of the serial sensor has an timer overflow bug: 32 signed integer timer running at 1kHz overflows into negative numbers after ~16 days; if the sensor's firmware does crash due to that, it'll likely take the USB connection with it. – *Suggestion:* Hack a custom USB cable with a P-channel MOSFET in the Vbus line, controlled by one of the RPi's GPIO pins (https://imgur.com/a/XXAwbhr). The MOSFET will conduct if the GPIO is actively pulled low. Add a cron job, that toggles the GPIO low-high-1ms-low every night, thereby resetting the sensor.

Comment: Does this help? https://en.opensuse.org/HCL:Raspberry_Pi4

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestions.
@Datenwolf:  I would never ever guessed that this is a possibility. I will try to do this.
Vbus is pin 1 of the USB connector.